# Option menu style change on change of style of activity in manifest

Tags: android

Initially in the manifest when i don't set any theme inside the activity tag my option menu look like this which is default..

But once i set this theme `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`  in the activity tag of my manifest file the option menu style changes.

Screen shots after adding `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"`

[image] 
Why this happen.

Comment: What android version are you using for development ?

Comment: @ChiragRaval actually i edit my question, so the final screen shot that i got after adding ur code is shown..here all the icons are missing that i have used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<activity
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Look Here For [Android Holo themes with backwards compatibility](http://www.chilisapps.com/blog/2012/04/17/support-holo-and-older-themes-in-android/)

**Edit** Try `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` in menu.xml file.  Look at this for [More](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Android-Action-Bar-from-the-Options-Menu.aspx)

Comment: As of Android 3.0, the options menu has been superseded by the Action Bar.

Comment: Nope it shows without icon only...but in galaxy note which has android 4.0.4 version how it shows menu with icon..i update the latest screen shot that i got after doing ur change.